# I can't add two variables in javascript. It either ignores the second variable or it concatenates if I change the order of the variables to be added.

Tags: javascript

I can't add two variables in javascript. It either ignores the second variable or it concatenates if I change the order of the variables to be added.

```
var total = zbv[0] + zval + zter;


total = total.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("ztotalvalue").innerHTML = total;
var nfa = Number(googForm.nfa.value);
alert(total);
alert(nfa)
var equity = nfa + total;
alert(equity);
```

Comment: You can only safely add numbers, since add uses the same operator as concat. Casting to numbers is easy, as you already know.

Answer (score 1):

`.toFixed()` return string, you can

```
var equity = nfa + +total // +total will cast string to number
```

Comment: Why not cast it to a number the readable way? `+` is what minifiers use to save 6 bytes. Or even cooler: `equity = nfa - -total`

Answer (score -2):

Well your question is poorly worded. Second if something is being concatenated, than that must mean it's a string (so that answers your question). You need to convert to integer and clean up your code. To debug your code use console.log, open element inspector and go to 'console'.